# Is it possible to animate a change to innerHTML using CSS only?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

My pure-JS script is changing the text inside a `<p>` element simply by using `innerHTML`. Is it possible to animate this change with CSS only, without using jQuery? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Animate in what way? You are changing the content, not the way the content looks!

Comment: Yes, I'm changing the content. Specifically, I'm generating a new random sentence to go inside the `<p>` element when I click a button. Currently, the sentence just changes in a snap. I'd like to have something more smooth, such as maybe the old sentence fading out and the new one sliding in from the left, or something like that.

Comment: Set a transition to the div height and width and set the content to autoexpand. Once you add content it should make an effect automatically

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before setting innerHTML add some class to the container, which through CSS set the pre-animation state, then set innerHTML and remove that class. if the container has transition set it should animate to clean state.

```
 .container {
        transition: all 1s;
        max-height: 300px;
    }

    .container.pre-animation {
        opacity:0;
        max-height: 0;
    }
```

`setTimeout` to make sure it effect more visible

```
var innerHTMLString = '<h1> I am H1 </h1>';

var container = document.querySelector('.container')

container.classList.add('pre-animation');
container.innerHTML = innerHTMLString +'ravi';
setTimeout(function(){
    container.classList.remove('pre-animation')
},100)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I follow.... Here, please look at what I'm trying to do: http://fbracht.github.io/yurator/ Would your method help me animate the sentence substitution that happens when you click the image? (This is a very simple joke site I'm making with a friend as a birthday present to another friend [the bearded pictured guy], it's a sentence generator with sentences this guy would be likely to say.)

Comment: should be. but it depends on what animation but you want to make. In this case, you need to fade out current sentence `opacity:0` and then change inner html and animate it back to `opacity:1`

Comment: This answer has the right idea, but it needs two modifications to make it work. The setTimeout needs to be 1000 milliseconds, not 100, to match the CSS transition duration. And the line which updates innerHTML needs to move down one line, so it is *inside* the setTimeout function.